# MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving error [3780]

Tags: mysql, r

I am using RMariaDB with the code

```
ALTER TABLE `general_pop_estimates` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_code`);
```

and it gives the error

> Error: Referencing column 'country_code' and referenced column 'country_code' in foreign key constraint 'general_pop_estimates_ibfk_1' are incompatible. [3780]

This is in spite them having same character type as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `country_code` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(255)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `general_pop_estimates` (
  `gen_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estimates` int,
  `country_code` varchar(255)
);
```

I tried to use as a remedy

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

but the issue persisted.

I am not sure what is the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output (not the code which you use for creation) for both tables. The codes itself are correct: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e38992d63881810b8acea3cd668a193)

Comment: Please review Conditions and Restrictions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: PS. I use MySQL version 8 in the fiddle, alter to your actual version (the code validity will remain nevertheless).

Comment: @Akina I am using Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL. I sit the same version you are using?

Comment: I don't remember. Open provided link to the fiddle and add `SELECT VERSION();` query to it.

Comment: OK thanks! I will have a look at it